# Spotify iOS SDK re-streaming/listen together apps

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

I was looking online at the Spotify iOS SDK documentation and found this: "The iOS SDK is explicitly prohibited from use for in-car apps, re-streaming aka “listen together” apps, alarm tones, ring-tones, voice-assistants, and offline experiences for wearable or other devices." I was curious what was meant by "listen together apps." I was hoping to create an app in which users in the same place can queue up songs to a shared queue. Is this in violation? What if the users are all Spotify users? Can this be monetized?

Comment: You should find a suitable forum to ask this question. I feel this is out for scope of stack overflow!

Comment: @AkshanshThakur Spotify's Developer support website links to posting a question on Stack Overflow but thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about licensing, not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

Ari from Spotify here - we can answer technical implementation questions but can't interpret the Terms of Service for you. We recommend consulting legal counsel for help with the terms. Regarding monetization, all commercial integrations must be approved by Spotify. You can submit a request for commercial approval directly in the Spotify for Developers Dashboard by clicking "Create a Client ID" and then selecting "Yes" when asked about commercial use.